# How to check whether a object is expired or not in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to check whether a object is expired or not by using:-

```
if (Token.objects.get(content=token).DatePosted-timezone.now())<'1 days':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

It is producing following error:-

```
 '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'str'
```

my question is hpw can i convert `0 days` into a `datetime.timedelta` object?

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime.timedelta` takes days as arguments. You can compare it like this

```
from datetime import timedelta
if (Token.objects.get(content=token).DatePosted-timezone.now())<timedelta(days=1):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `.days` attribute of [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
delta = Token.objects.get(content=token).DatePosted-timezone.now()
if delta.days < 1:
    # Do things
```